# Public AWS API to fetch instance details(memory, vCPU, etc) for a given EC2 instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to build a project(**in java**) in which given a EC2 instance type, I should be able to find what is the configured memory, vCPU's etc for that service. Basically information as present in this website: https://www.ec2instances.info/

I have tried a lot of public AWS APIs for this but unable to find something exactly suiting my use case. **Ps, AWS CLI is not an option since I have to do it automatically from code.**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DescribeInstanceTypes` API to retrieve the details of the instance types that are offered in a location. More info about the API, how you can filter, and the details of its response can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceTypes.html).